# PhpStorm - POST request not working, GET request does on localhost

Tags: php, post, xampp, localhost, phpstorm

When using PhpStorm, when attempting to do a $_POST request on localhost, the actionable function or page I wish to direct to does not receive any data in either $_POST or $_REQUEST, however when doing a $_GET request, it does work and data is sent.

test.php page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
<body>
    <form action="test2.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="queryform"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        <hr/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.php page...

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

- PhpStorm version 2016.3.2
- PHP language level 7.1
- CLI Interpreter 7.1.1
- OS = macSierra

Issue appears to effect me regardless of what php language and cli interpreter I use

Comment: This means that you are using PhpStorm's built-in simple web server (URL will be like `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/file.php`) which currently has issues with POST requests -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317 . Solution -- use proper web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/tec) or [PHP's own web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) instead. PhpStorm uses built-in web serve when you use `Open in Browser` or alike action and you do not have any Deployment entry configured (that's where URL comes from).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem appears to be specific to PhpStorm as issue can be reproduced on another machine running windows 10

**Fix**

When placing test.php and test2.php into my XAMPP 7.1 localhost directory, the issue does not appear, this also resolves the issue when placing files into WAMP directory on windows 10

Comment: Yes I did the same, on my windows 10, and xampp its working fine, No problem at all. When i saw your post i did on my localhost and working fine.