# JQuery AJAX Post Not Posting Data To PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can't seem to get any data posting with JQuery AJAX to PHP.
None of the answers I find give a clear explanation or solution.

JQuery AJAX Post:

```
$.post("requestlogin.php", {
        SignedIn: false,
        TokenID: 12345
    },
    function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data );
    });
```

requestlogin.php:

```
<?php
    $SignedIn = $_POST["SignedIn"];
    $TokenID = $_POST["TokenID"];
    echo $SignedIn . ' - ' . $TokenID;
?>
```

The only thing showing in the alert box is "Data:  - ".

Is the data not getting posted? Is PHP unable to see the data? Is the data being incorrectly formatted for the JQuery Post?

`var_dump($_REQUEST);` and `var_dump($_POST);` each print `array(0){}`..

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try to debug your AJAX request using the network tab of chrome console,  seeing if the file has correctly been called by the AJAX request

Comment: I can see in the chrome window `requestlogin.php` is being called.

Comment: can you try to change `False` to `false` please?

Comment: Still unable to retrieve the posted data. Chrome's networking tab shows a "Form Data" entry with my posted data upon selecting `requestlogin.php` from the list.

Comment: if you inspect the request do you see that the parameters have been correctly sent to the server?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that. It looks as if JQuery is doing it's job but PHP is confused. This is what I can see in the Network tab after selecting `requestlogin.php` http://i.imgur.com/GNv5Lv4.png

Comment: It may have [something to do with PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262856/1022914) that you seem to be using.

Comment: @KKlouzal in the screenshot you sent me, can you please click on the `response` tab and screen me that one as well

Comment: @Mikey Response Tab: http://i.imgur.com/fEKaN9a.png You can see the output from the var_dump's here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with PHPStorm not able to transmit anything but GET data. Switched over to WAMP for development and things are running smoothly!

Should have started with this setup from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'requestlogin.php',
    data: { SignedIn: false,
    TokenID: 12345},
    dataType: 'text', 
    cache: false,
    error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(textStatus);},
    success: function (data, textStatus, xmlhttp){
    alert(data); }
});
```

Your problem is most likely the fact that you don't specify a data type in the $.post() method and it's sending back a xmlhttp response as 'data' in your complete function which will reading "Object object" or "" when you use it in a string. I avoid $.get and $.post because I always have problems with them personally so I only remember the prototype for $.ajax, sorry lol. Either way debugging with this type of problem is made easy when you use the console in the browser to confirm the files content. If you don't know how to access the console in the browser just right-click in whatever browser your using, select inspect/inspect code and select the console tab on the window that appears.

Comment: Your type attribute has to be a string, not a `post` variable. Same thing for the `url` parameter. In addition your parameter `Signed in` contains a space which is not allowed in the JSON object to send to the server. Moreover, the default type of data is automatically detected by jQuery `ajax` method. Here the doc: `dataType
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).` 
I don't really think that the reason of the issue is the use of the shortcut `post` or the missing `dataType` field.

Comment: Sorry about the errors, I'm typing on my phone so I'm having a little trouble with accuracy. I'll fix it thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use:

```
if((isset( $_POST["SignedIn"]))&&(isset($_POST["TokenID"]))){
  $SignedIn = $_POST["SignedIn"];
  $TokenID = $_POST["TokenID"];
    echo $SignedIn . ' - ' . $TokenID;
}
```

and keep the same Jquery code:

```
$.post('requestlogin.php',
    {
        SignedIn: false,
        TokenID: 12345
    },
    function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data );
    });
```